# Cannot seed data as says 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I just started a new MVC 5 EF 6 project and added 1 simple model:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int TeamNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

Then followed these steps:
- Build solution
- Add ScaffoldedItem
- enable-migrations
- add-migration initial-create
- Added seed data:

```
    var teams new List<Team>
    {
        new Team { TeamNo = 2600, Name = "C" },
        new Team { TeamNo = 4000, Name = "VB" }
    };
    teams.ForEach(c => context.Teams.Add(c));
    context.SaveChanges();
```

- update-database

This worked as expected.

Then I added a second Model (that has 1-1 relationship to Shop):

```
public class Shop
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ShopNo{ get; set; }
    public shopFormat ShopFormat { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }
    public int TeamNo { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I then performed same EF steps:
- Build solution
- Add ScaffoldedItem
- add-migration shops

Then when I try to enter seed data in the configuration the Intellisense does not pickup the Shop properties. I can type in:

```
var shops = new List<Shop>
{
new Shop { }
};
```

but when I type ShopNo = 1010, i get the error: project.Migrations.Shop does not contain a definition for 'ShopNo'.

The Configuration file includes:
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

Can anyone please help me as I am pulling my hair trying to understand what I have done wrong or has gone wrong.

Kind regards
Craig

Comment: I have fixed it by removing the Migrations folder, deleting the App_Data/Database file and then repeating the migrations steps.

I think the cause of the problem was that I didnt add the DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None) bit to Shop model the first time.
HOwever, I did add a migration when I changed it, but it did not update the model properly.

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this issue without deleting the database and having to re-apply migrations and data seeding?

Regards

Comment: You should put that as the answer to the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by removing the Migrations folder, deleting the App_Data/Database file and then repeating the migrations steps.